# What effect do Powered Points have?

Tags: terra-battle

The hints and tips section mentions Powered Points in passing, but it doesn't actually describe what they do. What happens when you activate one during an attack?

[image: Help section screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include a power point in a chain attack, the rest of your attacks for that turn will do greatly increased damage as long as the power orb activates first.  This will event affect other chains that do not include the power orb.

Its also possible they make all skills trigger 100% of the time, I'll update if I see a failed skill trigger on a power point.

Comment: Do they also affect skill activation rate? I feel like I see skills trigger more frequently if a point has been activated, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Brysonic I also noticed it but I can't be sure.  I think they MIGHT make the chain skills trigger 100% of the time.